# C_(visual)_Debug Error_ Run-Time Check Failure #2 -S

Tags: c, arrays

I want to reverse numbers of array,
but I can't understand why it didn't run.

Thanks for explaining what does `Debug Error_ Run-Time Check Failure #2 -S` mean..

Thanks,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    int size, i, j;
    int temp = 0;
    size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); //use this for changing size
    printf("first_array :");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= (size / 2); i++)
    {
        j = size - i;
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    printf("Riv_array :");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It was a better idea you created a separate function named `reverse_array` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array index starts from 0  in C and your array has 5 elements so arr[4] is the last element but your code:

```
j = size - i;
arr[j];
```

when `i=0` access to  arr[5], this is your code error: **Array index out of bound**.

you should use `j = size - i-1;` to point to the last element of array,  not `j = size - i;`
see this working sample (your sample code with some edit):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int size, i, j;
    int temp = 0;
    size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); //use this for changing size
    printf("first_array :");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i <= (size / 2); i++)
    {
        j = size - i - 1;
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
    printf("Riv_array :");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

another way to reverse array using pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(int* p, int count){
    int temp;
    int* q = p + count - 1; // point to the end
    count /= 2;
    while (count--) {
        temp = *p;
        *p++ = *q;
        *q-- = temp;
    }
}
void print_array(int *p, int count){
    while (count--) printf("%d ", *p++);
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int count = ((&arr)[1] - arr);
    print_array(arr, count); 
    reverse(arr, count);
    print_array(arr, count);
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3 4 5
5 4 3 2 1
```